# I wonder how we can setup the clients to continue working even if all hazelcast cluster is down?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jhipster, hazelcast

I wonder how we can setup the clients to continue working even if the hazelcast remote cluster is down?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a capability called non-stop client that will allow clients to continue to work normally and retrieve data from NearCache if there is one enabled. This is slated to come out in near future.

Other than that, you can set various timeouts on clients, see below for example:

Connection retry: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#configuring-client-connection-retry

Operation retry: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-redo-operation

Various disconnect handling scenarios are captured here, will certainly help: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.1/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-redo-operation